# Special character in DOMPDF

Tags: dompdf

We are copying content from word doc in CKEDITOR in Drupal. In generated pdf "?" is coming for some character.
Also at some places content is overlapping.

When same is seen in website, its appearing fine.

Any help in this?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of dompdf? Sounds like an older version that had problems handling non-Windows ANSI characters. As of v0.6.0 handling should be better but you can't use one of the core fonts. Try one of the bundled DejaVu fonts.

Comment: Also, it would help to know what characters are causing problems. And how you are taking the content from CKEditor and passing it to dompdf.

Comment: @BrianS I guess its version 6. We are copying content from word and pasting it is CKEditor. some character causing issue are "-", '.

Comment: Not sure why these would be causing issues. Usually you see this with characters that fall outside Windows ANSI encoding when you're using the core PDF fonts (Helvetica, Times, Courier). Can you view the source after pasting into CKEditor?